# If $g(z)$ is analytic function, and $g(z)=O(|z|)$ and g(z) is never zero then show that g(z) is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $g(z)$ is analytic function, and $g(z)=O(|z|)$ and g(z) is never zero then show that g(z) is constant.

My attempt:

I could show using cauchy estimates that $g(z)=O(z) = a_0+a_1z$. Now g(z) is analytic and never zero it means $z \neq \frac{-b}{a}$. It means how can we conclude that it is constant?

Comment: Just look at your derived equation, which is $g(z) = a_0 + a_1z$. If $g$ is not constant, then $a_1 \neq 0$. Can you then find a zero for $g$?

Comment: It should be clear that if $a_1\ne 0,$ then $a_0+a_1z =  0$ if $z= -a_0/a_1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have that $g(z)$ is linear by the usual bounds for the coefficients of the MacLaurin expansion, the only way $g(z)$ has to avoid a zero is to be a non-zero constant.

By the fundamental Theorem of Algebra, this has a nice generalization: if $g(z)$ is holomorphic, non-vanishing and $O(|z|^m)$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}^*$, then $g$ is a non-zero constant.

Comment: Sir i did not understand. I have not reached till that point. Fundamental theorem of algebra when googled says, given n degree polynomial, then there will be n roots. 

From your statement, if  g(z) is holomorphic(means analytic thru out in finite complex space), non-vanishing means no zeroes for g(z) which is of  order $O(|z|^m)$, Whether such g(z) exists? for ex., any function of degree m will have roots in complex space right? [pls see below comment for continuation]

Comment: this is what is fundamental theorem of algebra. I am surprised at this generalization. I am just a beginner. Please elaborate so that i can easily understand the concept. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you tell me a book which has good explanation on this?